# how to call method with interface as parameter

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

how to call method with interface as parameter xamarin form. I need to call this method and pass the interface

```
        //Method I am trying to call 
        public virtual unsafe void Check (global::Com.Test.Precheck.Client.ITestClientListener listener)
        {
            const string __id = "check.(Lcom/test;)V";
            try 
            {
                JniArgumentValue* __args = stackalloc JniArgumentValue [1];

                __args [0] = new JniArgumentValue ((listener == null) ? IntPtr.Zero : ((global::Java.Lang.Object) listener).Handle);

                _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (__id, this, __args);

            } 
            finally 
            {
                global::System.GC.KeepAlive (listener);
            }
        }
```

> Error  Specified cast is not valid
> where I try

```
//Class that inherits ITestClientListener interface 
    TestClientListener obj = new TestClientListener();
```

then call Check method that accepts `ITestClientListener`

```
Check((ITestClientListener)obj)

  public class TestClientListener : ITestClientListener
    {
        public TestClientListener()
        {

        }
        public IntPtr Handle => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int JniIdentityHashCode => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public JniObjectReference PeerReference => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public JniPeerMembers JniPeerMembers => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public JniManagedPeerStates JniManagedPeerState => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Disposed()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DisposeUnlessReferenced()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Finalized()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnError(int p0)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnFinish(string p0, string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4, string p5)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SetJniIdentityHashCode(int value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SetJniManagedPeerState(JniManagedPeerStates value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SetPeerReference(JniObjectReference reference)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void UnregisterFromRuntime()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whats the problem? Do you have a variable of type ITestClientListener  in scope for the caller to pass in?

Comment: Yes I created a class that inherits ITestClientListener . then 
 
 //Class that inherits ITestClientListener interface 
 TestClientListener obj = new TestClientListener();
    
 then call Check method that accepts ITestClientListener
 
 Check((ITestClientListener)obj)
 
 //Error  Specified cast is not valid

Comment: At which line you get the error? could yo share ITestClientListener, and TestClientListener ?

Comment: don't cast the object, just pass the object directly.

Comment: we have to see `TestClientListener` source, becuase what you describe should work

Comment: Could you provide the code source of  class `TestClientListener` here ?

Comment: I have added code for TestClientListener on the original code

Comment: Best guess: there are two different `ITestClientListener` interfaces here. It's hard to know for sure, but you shouldn't even need the cast.